# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider when adding $uibModalInstance to controller

Tags: angularjs

When I add $uibModalInstance to my controller I get the error:

Unknown provider: `$uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl`

My controller is defined as:

```
angular.module('myWebApp.controllers').
    controller('EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, eventData) {
});
```

I have another controller that defines the open function:

```
controller('modalCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
    $scope.open = function (template, instance, size) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: template,
            controller: instance,
            size: size
        });
    };
}).
```

Then I want to pass the controller that will handle a specific instance of a modal, in this case `EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl`.

My app is defined as:

```
var app = angular.module('myWebApp', [
    'myWebApp.services',
    'myWebApp.controllers',
    'ui.router',
    'duScroll',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
    'angular-loading-bar'
]);
```

What am I missing?

EDIT ----

Here's how EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl is linked to the view in ui-Router.

```
   $stateProvider
        .state('event', {
            url: '/event',
            params: {
                eventId: null
            },
            resolve: {
                eventData: ['$http', '$stateParams', function ($http, $stateParams) {
                    console.log('EventId: ' + $stateParams.eventId);
                    return $http.get('http://localhost:10569/api/eventView/' + $stateParams.eventId).then(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                }]
            },
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/events/event.html'
                    //controller: 'EventCtrl'
                },
                'eventHeader@event' : {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/events/event-header.html',
                    controller: 'EventHeaderCtrl'
                },
                'eventOverviewTab@event': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/events/event-overview-tab.html',
                    controller: 'EventOverviewTabCtrl'
                },
                'eventDSOTab@event': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/events/event-dso-tab.html',
                    controller: 'EventDSOTabCtrl'
                },
                'eventAdditionalInformationTab@event': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/events/event-additional-information-tab.html',
                    controller: 'EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl'
                },
                'eventFooter@event': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/events/event-footer.html',
                    controller: 'EventFooterCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you create a plunkr or fiddle for your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Where you have `$uibModalInstance` now should just be `$uibModal`.  Use `$uibModalInstance` when you want to actually create a modal.  [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) is the [official](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) example for how to use `$uibModal`.

Comment: Remove `function (template, instance, size) {
        var modalInstance = `.  Those parts are unnecessary.  You want `$scope.open` to be the `$uibModal.open()` function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to inject '$uibModal' into your controller.

Check out the angular ui docs here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

EDIT:

Change this

```
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: template,
    controller: instance,
    size: size
```

to this

```
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: template,
    controller: EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl,
    size: size
```

Comment: I've done that. It causes anything else that I'm injecting into EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl to fail with the same unknown provider error.

I can get the example from the uiBootstrap site to work if I keep the two separate controllers in their example. But as soon as I try to replace ModalInstanceCtrl with EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl it fails. It fails even when I copy the code from ModalInstanceCtrl into EventAdditionalInformationCtrl. If I can't have the modal under my controller it's useless cause I can't extract the data from the modal into the controller that needs it.

Comment: @Legion What controller needs it? You can pass in the parent scope to the modal's and put the data on the parent.

Comment: EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl (EAITC) is the controller that needs the data from the modal. There's no parent child relationship between ModalInstanceCtrl and EAITC. EAITC is linked to a view defined under a ui-router state. ModalInstanceCtrl is just another controller in my app.controllers.js file.

Comment: @senschen I've updated the question showing how EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl is linked to the view

Comment: @Legion Well, it might not be the best idea, but you could but your data on `$rootScope`.  Everything has access to that.

Comment: @senschen I thought about doing something like that, but then you have to setup broadcasts/listeners in order to know when to fetch the data from `$rootScope`. I don't know if it's feasible but for now I'm just going to work under the assumption that you can't do modals with angularjs and try to design around it.